# Does Google Drive SDK allow multiple concurrent logins?

Tags: google-drive-api

If so, how do you suggest handling Authentication & separation for multiple concurrent logins?

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-login case, auth permissions will show an account selector before asking for permissions for the required scopes. You can use `login_hint` parameter to pre-select the account without any user interaction. More details are on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl

Comment: The question is about multiple accounts.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Burcu. That still sounds to me like only ONE single account is permitted login, and not MULTIPLE accounts concurrently connected.

Comment: You need to request permissions for both accounts, if you would like to connect both accounts concurrently. But there is no way to ask for permissions for both at the same time.